# Should the "bs4" Tag be merged with the "beautifulsoup" Tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

As a Python user, I just searched for an answer using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I noticed on a handful of questions, the OPs would use the [bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4) tag as well as the [beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) tag.

[beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup), at the time of this posting, has 9,618 postings.

[bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4), at the time of this posting, has 434 postings

When [bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4) and [beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) are used together, there are 233 postings.

This is over half of the [bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4) tags being used alongside with [beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). In fact the [bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4) tag's info points to [beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). To a Python user, these tags mean the same thing (with [beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) being the one that makes the most sense). Should these tags be merged?

There is also no other version that currently has a tag. In fact the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1) on version three reads:

> This package is OBSOLETE. It has been replaced by the beautifulsoup4 package. You should use Beautiful Soup 4 for all new projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely. As the [#2 BeautifulSoup question answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/beautifulsoup/topusers) I can tell you that the tag should just be a synonym.

I've made it so.